# Preventing Visual Studio 2010 from embedding resources (images) into exe file

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, resources

I add new image file into project by clicking Add Resource -> Add Existing File... After that i change Persistence to "Linked at compile time" from Properties.
My problem is that all of those files getting embedded into final exe file. I wish to create small exe file that load those images during execution from Resource folder. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the images into the resource file.  Rather put them in your solution and mark them as "content". then when you open them, open them with normal file operations.